# React-native + apollo: Network request failed

Tags: react-native, apollo

I'm trying to resolve Network request failed on IOS in React-Native project. The current moment is I'm trying to make HTTPS request for checking authorization in Apollo client, and everywhere is only answer that I should change info.plist in IOS, but I have changed it already, and still getting an error :(
Also I tried to use IP address in link, but it didn't work.

Please, help me to resolve it.

---

client.js

```
const Login = onError(({error}) => {
  console.log(e);
  if (error && error.statusCode === 401) {
    onLogin();
  }
});


const ApolloLink = new HttpLink({ uri: 'https://link', credentials: 'include' });
const Link = Login.concat(ApolloLink);

export default new ApolloClient({
  link: Link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export function ApolloClient(operation) {
  return makePromise(execute(Link, operation));
}
```

---

info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

UPDATE: finally found out that in my case it was a problem of the Webpack. Thank you all!

Comment: What error are you getting

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead of yours and change 127.0.0.1 with your laptop IP

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>127.0.0.1</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't help nor localhost neither IP :(

Comment: Try to use IP-LAPTOP:8081/debugger-ui instead of localhost:8081/debugger-ui,
IP-LAPTOP = the ip you used on <key></key> , I solve it with those two steps